# Taking arrays of pointers in function prototypes in header files: function declared void

Tags: c++

I'm a bit new to programming and ran into these errors tracing to the function prototype in the function header file and I think it may have something to do with the array of pointers it's getting.

error variable or field 'clean_up' declared void

error 'Button' was not declared in this scope

error 'buttons' was not declared in this scope

error expected primary variable before ']' token

```
    //Function.h

    #include "SDL/SDL.h"
    #include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
    #include <string>
    #include "functions.h"
    #include "globals.h"
    #include "Button.h"
    #include <fstream>

    void clean_up( Button *buttons[] ); // errors here

    //Function.cpp
  void clean_up( Button *buttons[] )

    {
        SDL_FreeSurface( background );
        SDL_FreeSurface( X );
        SDL_FreeSurface( O );

        for( int t = 0; t < TOTAL_BUTTONS; t++ )
        {
            delete buttons[ t ];
        }

        SDL_Quit();
    }
    //Button.h
    class Button
    {
    private:

    SDL_Rect box;
    SDL_Surface *sprite;

    public:


        bool in_use;
        bool xoro;
        int p_id;


Button( int x, int y, int id );
~Button();

void handle_events();

void show();

};

//Button.cpp

Button::Button( int x, int y, int id )
{
    box.x = x;
    box.y = y;
    box.w = 120;
    box.h = 120;
    in_use = false;
    p_id = id;
}
Button::~Button()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface( sprite );
}
```

I wasn't really sure where to look for a solution so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try to move the `Button` class definition to the `"Button.h"` header

Comment: Are you including the header files in the cpp files?

Comment: What lines give the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding forward declaration of class Button in the .h file.

Function.h

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include <string>
#include "functions.h"
#include "globals.h"
#include "Button.h"
#include <fstream>

class Button;
void clean_up( Button *buttons[] );
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the class should be declared before the function declaration/definition.

Answer (score 0):

Function.h includes too many header files.  It only depends on Button.

So only include Button.h.  or even better, just forward declare class Button;

This will remove the problem in function.h, but it probably the will pop up elsewhere.

As a psychic guess, you are missing a ; or a } somewhere.